# Rails 4 - Customizing Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I'm developing a marketplace app where vendors can list items to sell. I have two routes that I need to customize.

1) My product listing routes are based on `resources listings` - this makes the product show page route be `/listings/:id`. For seo purposes, I want the product name to be part of the route so `/listings/:id/:name`. But since I'm using `resources listings`, I'm not sure how to specify that I want to change the show page route.

2) My vendor page (which shows for vendor specific listings) route is `get '/listings/s/:id' => 'listings#vendor', as: 'vendor'`. I want to add the vendor name to the route so it is `/listings/:vendor/:id` - the vendor name is in the User model. The Listing model has a user_id foreign key. How do I reference the vendor name in the listing route?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use slugs, not complicated routes, see this gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id